# Need a way to have excel show items I have used already from drop down list

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007

This is my first time asking. I have an excel sheet, new to excel but love to learn.

I worked out how to make drop down lists and I have a list of cars that are being used. The user in sheet 1 selects the car from the list of 8, then fills in how long its being used for (with the price, etc) till the total is at the end R3.

Is there a way I can make it so that the next user doesn't select the same car as the first user from the drop down list? Or is it highlighted that the item the first user used is already in use? or is there any other way to do this, like maybe once the first car is finished with it returns into the drop down list. Lets say after the end date is filled in cell D3.

Maybe too much to ask but hope it can be done. 
Thanks to anyone who can help

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to do this using Data Validation, which I am assuming you used to create your lists in the first place. Not knowing how your sheet is setup, this answer can only be generic in nature.

To do what you are asking uses tables, data validation and formulas to hide previously used items from the list.  You will need to do the following;

1. Set up the Main Table
2. Create the List of Items
3. Calculate if a name has been used by using a formula
4. Create the list of unused names
5. Name the Dynamic List of Unused Names
6. Apply the Excel Data Validation

[image]

Here is a link to the page with step-by-step instructions how to set this up - [Hide Used Items in Drop Down List](http://www.contextures.com/xlDataVal03.html#calcused).